# IE9 Waiting 7-10 seconds before starting to stream a video from Amazon S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3, internet-explorer-9, video-streaming

http://screencast.com/t/NKb9erVyd0

I'm using the Projekktor HTML5 video player.  The video starts playing immediately in all browsers except for internet explorer.  In developer tools IE shows a huge Wait time.  What is this wait time and why does IE feel the need to waste 10 seconds of my user's life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That MP4 has the index at the end of the file so Internet Explorer downloads the entire file before starting playback.  I don't know why it does this, but you can run QTIndexSwapper on that MP4 to fix the problem.

http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/

Comment: Thanks barsh.  I follow Renaun's blog, but I guess I missed this one.